# Why aren't runnable code snippets formatted correctly within lists?

Tags: bug, code-formatting, markdown-preview, stack-snippets, list

- Consider the following code snippet.

  ```js
      console.log("this line is all right");
      console.log("but this line is indented");
  ```

  This should be a part of the same bullet point but it's not.

The indentation seems to be correct. So, why is this happening? How do I fix it?

---

**Edit:** If you edit the question you'll notice that it looks different in the preview.

[image: This is what it looks like when you edit it.]

Comment: It didn't look the same in the preview.

Comment: adding a screenshot would help clarifying the confusion.

Comment: @IamMonica No, the code snippet in the final output is also indented by an extra four spaces.